# UITextView embedded in a UITableViewCell not resizing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate:

```
Status *status = nil;
status = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* postvalue = status.statusContent;
cell.postContent.scrollEnabled = NO;

CGSize mysize = [postvalue sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
CGRect frame = cell.postContent.frame;
frame.size.height = mysize.height;
cell.postContent.frame = frame;

cell.postContent.text = postvalue;
```

Where cell.postContent is a textView

And here is my code that resizes the cells:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
   Status *status = nil;
   status = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString* postvalue = status.statusContent;

   return 100 + [self heightForText:postvalue];
}


-(CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)text
{
   NSInteger MAX_HEIGHT = 2000;
   UITextView * textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 226, MAX_HEIGHT)];
   textView.text = text;
   textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];// your font
   [textView sizeToFit];

   return textView.frame.size.height;
}
```

This is what it results in:

[image]

I have replaced the user name with the height calculated in the cellForRow.. delegate so you can see the height is being calculated correctly, and the cell is resizing correctly, but the textview is not - there are quite a few more lines than you can't see. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: try to set the frame in subclassed cell itself...

Comment: I have no access to the cell content from there @Shan

Comment: You can return the appropriate height (height of your text view + padding) in -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath.

Comment: check the answer i posted ..

Comment: i edited my answer check now

Answer (score 0):

That's because you shouldn't create new textField (which you also forgot to add as a subview) but resize the cell's outlet. Try to set textField's height in cellForRow when the cell is created

Comment: I am doing this already...

CGSize mysize = [postvalue sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
CGRect frame = cell.postContent.frame;
frame.size.height = mysize.height;
cell.postContent.frame = frame;

cell.postContent is the outlet

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` takes some default padding around it so this might be issue. Set `contentInset` of the `UITextView` by code.

```
// this is how we define setContentInset method
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right)];

// and you should do like this
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8, -8, -8 ,-8)];
```

Answer (score 0):

u can access it's content view i think, here is the code,
i am using some values for testing it works fine, go through this hope helps u ... :)

disable auto layout for textfield

in CustomCelll.h file

```
   @interface CustomCelll : UITableViewCell
   //i think u hav an outlet for textview
   @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *postContent;
   @property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *message;//you get the message to set the height

   in CustomCelll.m file

   @implementation CustomCelll
   @synthesize postContent;
   @synthesize imageView;
   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
  {
      self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
      if (self) {
      //heare i am adding the button
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
        self.postContent.frame = CGRectZero;//initially set it zero
        self.postContent.font = font;
        }
      return self;

  }

   - (void)layoutSubviews
    {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     CGSize size = [self findMessgeStringHeight];//you can ge the size
     //set frame for ur label
     self.postContent.frame = CGRectMake(103, 8, size.width + 10,size.height + 10);//set the height here(for your case) and disable auto layout  
     self.postContent.text = self.message;//set the message
   }

  - (CGSize)findMessgeStringHeight
   {

         NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.message attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f] }];
        CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){225, MAXFLOAT}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
        CGSize requiredSize = rect.size;

       return requiredSize; //finally u return your height
  }


   //in your controller

   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    CustomCelll *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BDCustomCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Empty" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
     }
   cell.message = @"hello, how are u, it been so long since we met, how's the weather there, here too cold, i am going to my mom's home may be i will stay there for 2 or 3 weeks";
   return cell;
   }

   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

      NSString *str = @"hello, how are u, it been so long since we met, how's the weather there, here too cold, i am going to my mom's home may be i will stay there for 2 or 3 weeks";//use same  sring to get the height

     NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]
 }];
     CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){225, MAXFLOAT}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
     CGSize requiredSize = rect.size;
     return requiredSize.height + 30;
   }
```

Comment: Isn't sizeWithFont deprecated? Also I don't see how this is entirely different to what I'm already doing

Comment: And also, why are you adding textView as a subview and not postContent?

Comment: ya thats becz without arc u can change it i did't release it wait i editing the my answer

Comment: are u using xib file for custom cell...? beck i am doing it through programatically

Comment: Yeah I'm using a xib, so I don't need to make the subviews programatically

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46001/discussion-between-shan-and-daniel-van-der-merwe)